# Is there a way to get Firestore document ID and data in one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, syncfusion

I am building a react app with Syncfusion and Firebase backend.
I fetch data from Firestore and would like to get the document ID as well as the document data in a single object. I have created 2 states, one that just returns the data and another that returns an object of ID and data. When I use the one with just the data as the data source for syncfusion Gridcomponent, it works well, but the one with both ID and data does not work.

State:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [itemsWithId, setItemsWithId] = useState([]);
```

Getting data from Firestore and setting to state:

```
  const itemsList = await getItems();
  const finalItems = itemsList.docs.map((doc) => (doc.data()));
  const finalItemsWithId= itemsList.docs.map((doc) => ({data: doc.data(), id: doc.id}));

  setItems(finalItems);
  setItemsWithId(finalItemsWithId);
```

The Grid Component:

```
  <GridComponent
    id='gridComponent'
    dataSource={items.data}
    allowPaging
    allowSorting
    toolbar={[ExcelExport]}
    allowExcelExport
  >
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get that data with it's ID as part of one object or how to consume both the ID and data in the Grid Component.

Comment: Not unless you add the `id` field in the document as well. But the `finalItemsWithId` approach of mapping a new array is pretty common. Can you explain what is not working so we can check that issue? Please update your question with any errors.

Comment: As darmaraj mentioned can you update question wtih details.